# Is this a pythonic, i.e. right way to user context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

We have some code that creates SDE connections to an Oracle database. I want to create a wrapper class that will make the connections easier to manage. Is my attempt to do so pythonic?

Often in our python code we will want to connect to the same database in a few different ways in the same script. For example:

- Esri SDE with database authentication (DBA) user "A" and the default SDE version
- Esri SDE with database authentication user "B" and SDE version "something"
- Esri SDE with operating system authentication (OSA) and an SDE version
- A Oracle connection as user "C" with cx_Oracle

Right now we have a homegrown site package that does most of this work for us. But it has two problems that I have encountered:

- It is a little bit inefficient. For example, every time I need an SDE DBA connection I have to pass all of the information to the function: database, the path for the connection file, and user (if it is a DBA connection). It would be cool if I had a class that could know the database and the path information. Then I could just tell it what type of connection I needed, SDE or Oracle and the user/DBA or OAS info.
- The current code does not clean up well after itself. If it fails for whatever reason (or the developer forgets to call the cleanup function) connections are orphaned and build up over time. So, maybe we should use the with statement to ensure stuff gets cleaned up.

```
    import security
    from _ceaconnection import createConnection
    from _ceaconnection import deleteConnection
    import cx_Oracle
    from contextlib import contextmanager


    class ConnectionHelper:

        def __init__(self, database):
            self.database = database
            self.temp_path = security.tmpPath

        @contextmanager
        def sde_dba_connection(self, user, version=None):
            """
            Create dba sde connection
            :param version: sde version
            :param user: sde user (schema)
            :return: sde connection
            """
            connection = None
            try:
                password = security.get_password(self.database, user.lower())
                credentials = dict(server=self.database, user=user, password=password)
                connection = createConnection(credentials, self.temp_path, version=version)
                yield connection
            finally:
                if connection is not None:
                    deleteConnection(connection)

        @contextmanager
        def sde_osa_connection(self, version=None):
            """
            Create osa sde connection
            :param version: sde version
            :return: sde connection
            """
            connection = None
            try:
                connection = createConnection("OS", self.temp_path, server=self.database, version=version)
                yield connection
            finally:
                if connection is not None:
                    deleteConnection(connection)

        @contextmanager
        def oracle_connection_with(self, user):
            """
            create cx_oracle connection
            :param user: oracle user
            :return: oracle connection
            """
            password = security.get_password(self.database, user.lower())
            with cx_Oracle.connect("{u}/{p}@{db}".format(u=user, p=password, db=self.database)) as connection:
                yield connection
```

This code appears to work as expected when called:

```
connection_helper = ceaarcpy.ConnectionHelper('database')
    with connection_helper.sde_dba_connection('sde') as conn:
        # do some stuff
```

Comment: This looks good to me.  The use case of "I need to make sure this cleanup always happens when I'm done" is *exactly* what context managers are for.  :)

Comment: @SamStafford Thanks for the feedback!